# iOS Swift popViewController not released from memory?

Tags: swift, memory, memory-leaks

i am having issue with closing `UIViewcontroller` which is attached and opened from uiNavigationController , when i close/reopen the B `UIViewcontroller` the memory get increased every time i open it , but when i close it nothing happened the memory wont go down .

I've tried the following codes all same :

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    strongSelf.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

and

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {[unowned self] in
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

and

```swift
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

the B `UIViewctonroller` has only 1 image in storyboard no code is there .

> anyidea how to release Closed "pop" UIVIewcontroller from memory  ?

Comment: Please provide example project or more code, because your examples all do same thing and by themselves can't create memory-cycles

Comment: how you got B UIViewController is important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make sure you didn't set any strong pointers to that viewController (like navigation controller for example), otherwise that controller will get retained by the navigation controller
- Try to avoid using strong properties for IBOutlets.
- if your using self in your code make sure it's an optional self, using the [weak self] Swift Blocks 
  It will be be released if there are no other strong pointers to it